# too much slow for result anyone can give a boost (query working file for 10 records but take time for more records))

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, select

```
select a , b , c
from h1 where a  in
(
    select a
    from h1
    group by a
    having count(distinct b) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest adding the following index to your table:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON h1 (a, b, c);
```

Then, rewrite your query as follows:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM h1 t1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM h1 t2
    WHERE t1.a = t2.a
    GROUP BY t2.a
    HAVING MIN(t2.b) = MAX(t2.b)
);
```

The index ideally will let MySQL evaluate the aggregation subquery fairly quickly.  Note that the min/max trick is saying the same thing as requiring the distinct count to be 1.  Except in this version, an index can be used.

Comment: can you make this one also  select  a, b, c FROM 
 (  SELECT a,b,c,d
     FROM h1  where a in
    (
    select a
    from h1
    group by a
    having count(distinct b) = 1
    ))

Comment: @jais Tuning a query is often a one at a time thing.  You might want to open a new question.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient method should be `not exists`:

```
select h.a, h.b, h.c
from h1 h
where not exists (select 1 
                  from h1 hh
                  where hh.a = h.a and hh.b <> h.b
                 );
```

For performance, you want an index on `h1(a, b)`.

No aggregation is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you could try by using exists, in case of subquery  returned large  data set it may work better than in

```
select a , b , c
from h1 t1 where exists
(
    select 1
    from h1 t2
    t2.a=t1.a
    having count(distinct b) = 1
)
```

Comment: Most databases will optimize `WHERE IN` and `WHERE EXISTS` to the same thing.

Comment: ERROR: Syntax error: Encountered "t2" at line 17, column 5.
Error Code: 3000

Answer (score 0):

`IN ( SELECT ... )` can be terribly slow.  Aside from using `EXISTS(...)`, using 'derived table' is sometimes useful:

```
select  h1.a , h1.b , h1.c
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  a
            from  h1
            group by  a
            having  count(distinct b) = 1 
    ) AS x
    JOIN  h1 USING(a)
```